# How to redirect a internal GET request from maps.gstatic.com to maps.gstatic.cn when using google map API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map API for Chinese users. A js URL "http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?......" is used and most apis work fine. However, when I use the direction service, some resources such as icons are directed to .com domain while not .cn, which causes failed load. as can be seen from a figure below, an icon "http://**maps.gstatic.com**/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/subway2.png" was failed loading.

Actually, the icon will correctly load if I change the icon's url from **maps.gstatic.COM** to **maps.gstatic.CN**. The question is how to perform these changes. I've been searching through and getting no solutions. Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks!

[Error can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvG0m.png)

Comment: Does this work `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&region=CN">
</script>`? Got it from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried your suggestion, unfortunately, the problem remains the same. So far the only solution I can think of is to change the internal GET request for those icons. I am wondering if there are other solutions.

Comment: I'd try 2 things: 1) Try with `https://ditu.google.cn/maps/api/js` and see if it makes any difference. 2) If not, try opening a bug in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/558438).

Comment: ditu.google.cn and maps.google.cn are the same thing and they don't support https. I will report this to Google to see if there are any solutions. Thanks again.